# ajax Control Toolkit 4.1.40412.0 chart controls cannot be compiled?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using Ajax chart(Pie chart, Line chart, bar chart) in my project. All Reference  to this ajax is properly. And it worked well in the old version . When I upgrade to ajax Control Toolkit 4.1.40412.0 . I cannot compile my project anymore. The error display:

> `Warning   2   Element 'PieChart' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.`

I added in web.config:

```
 <pages validateRequest="false"  clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
             namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />

      </controls>

    </pages>
```

and in my HTML form:

```
 <asp:PieChart ID="PieChart1" runat="server" ChartHeight="535" ChartWidth="535"
                              Visible="true" borderstyle="None" forecolor="White"></asp:PieChart>
```

What is wrong with this version in my webconfig?
And I also remember to add Reference:
[image]

And its property is:
[image]

Comment: Is there no Chart control in ajax Control Toolkit 4.1.40412.0. So which is the  latest version that chart control available?

Comment: the latest stable version is 15.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `tagPrefix="asp"`. You are actually getting an error

> The type or namespace name '**PieChart**' does not exist in the namespace '**System.Web.UI.WebControls**' (*are you missing an assembly reference*?)

To make it work, change the tag prefix

web.config

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

markup

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:PieChart ID="PieChart1" runat="server" 
        ChartHeight="535" 
        ChartWidth="535"
        Visible="true" 
        BorderStyle="None" 
        ForeColor="White">
</ajaxToolkit:PieChart>
```

NuGet Package Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/

Comment: I download the latest version 15.1.3 but it is ony the installer file, where to get the binary ajaxxontroltoolkit to reference in the project.

Comment: whats your vs version? download using nuget.

Comment: VS 2010 Ultimate, install by download intstaller file